# HTML adding a barrier for images and other text

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <body style="background-color:#38a9e3;">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bs.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>


    <div id="main-sidebar">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="x.html"><h1>x</h1></a>
            <span>x</span>
        </div>

        <div class="navigation">
            <ul class="main-menu">
                <li class=""><a href="x.html">x</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="x.html">x</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="x.html">x</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="x.html">x</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="x.html">x</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

</div>
    <center></center>
</body>
</html>
```

Above is sample code that is for a task bar on a site, i will comment the css code below since putting it here will only cluster the question. How do i make it so on the right of the task bar is a separate area. Right now if i try add an image or write something it goes under it so i have to center everything and resize it which is really annoying. How could i edit the css or html to help me?

**Demo:** [jsfiddle.net/znu9ukk8](http://jsfiddle.net/znu9ukk8)

Comment: Does anyone know how i could show of the CSS files ?

Comment: Make a js fiddle example, try using display: block ir inline. Will be easier to tell with a demo. https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: are you able to start a chat with me ? i could try send you a download link through that and you could help me easier ?

Comment: Add everything to the website I have linked before. It will be easier for other guys to help you out and if someone encounters similar problem, they will be able to find a solution just by reading this topic.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/znu9ukk8/

Comment: i am testing section atm and if nothing better is found i will stick with it

Comment: You should stop using <center> in html5. Will take a look at your demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove center and section. Instead of that add this:

```
  <div class="test">
     Test...

      </div>
```

and for the css

```
.test {
    float: right;
}
```

You can set margin, width, height yourself. Just tell me if this is what you wanted to do. http://prntscr.com/bg5adn

Comment: is there an easy way of putting a margin after the sidebar to the end ? I am trying what you gave me now and it is working well but how do i set a good margin ?